# How to fetch results from spark sql using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently, I am new to spark and I am using python to write code in spark.

I am able to read from a parquet file and store the data in dataframe and as the temp table.

But it is not printing the results of the query executed. Please help in debugging this.

**Code:**

```
import os
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/"
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sc = SparkContext(master='local')
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
df_tract_alpha = sqlCtx.read.parquet("tract_alpha.parquet")
print (df_tract_alpha.columns)
sqlCtx.registerDataFrameAsTable(df_tract_alpha, "table1")
nt = sqlCtx.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) AS pageCount FROM table1 WHERE pp_count>=500").collect()
n1 = nt[0].pageCount
print n1
```

**This is giving result:**

```
 Column< pageCount['pageCount'] > instead of printing the value
```

Here is the stack trace

```
17/06/12 12:54:27 WARN BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_2 failed due to an exception
17/06/12 12:54:27 WARN BlockManager: Block broadcast_2 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vn/scripts/g_s_pipe/test_code_here.py", line 66, in 
    nt = sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) as pageCount FROM table1 WHERE pp_count>=500").collect()
  File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 310, in collect
    port = self._jdf.collectToPython()
  File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.collectToPython.
: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.lang.Object[] java.util.ArrayList.elementData accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @55deb90
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:335)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:278)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:169)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$getClassInfo$3.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$getClassInfo$3.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:330)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.getClassInfo(SizeEstimator.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.visitSingleObject(SizeEstimator.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.org$apache$spark$util$SizeEstimator$$estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTracker$class.takeSample(SizeTracker.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTracker$class.afterUpdate(SizeTracker.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTrackingVector.$plus$eq(SizeTrackingVector.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:866)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:702)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putSingle(BlockManager.scala:1234)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.(TorrentBroadcast.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.buildReader(ParquetFileFormat.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(ParquetFileFormat.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileSourceStrategy$.apply(FileSourceStrategy.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner.plan(SparkPlanner.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner$$anonfun$plan$1$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(SparkPlanner.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner$$anonfun$plan$1$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(SparkPlanner.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner$$anonfun$plan$1.apply(SparkPlanner.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner$$anonfun$plan$1.apply(SparkPlanner.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner$$anonfun$plan$1$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(SparkPlanner.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner$$anonfun$plan$1$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(SparkPlanner.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner$$anonfun$plan$1.apply(SparkPlanner.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner$$anonfun$plan$1.apply(SparkPlanner.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2523)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:547)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: This error is trigger on n1 = ntrac.show which is not in the code you have shared...

Comment: Also show doesn't return a value so I'm not sure why you are storing it in one...

Comment: sorry, i pasted the wrong stack, posting the right one... I was trying some other options instead of what is pasted in the question

Comment: Please check the updated trace now

Comment: I have updated my answer and it can't get more clear than that. As you see I'm using your actual code and ofc I have corrected the error with the collect method

Comment: well I am getting the same error with collect(). U can check the 5 line of my error.

Comment: if you run the code that I gave you it gives the same error ? it's not possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146415/discussion-between-viv-and-eliasah).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `collect` function take parentheses `()`

```
nt = sqlCtx.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) AS pageCount FROM table1 WHERE pp_count>=500") \
           .collect()
```

Example :

Let's check our parquet data first:

```
$> parquet-tools head data.parquet/
a = 1
pp_count = 500

a = 2
pp_count = 750

a = 3
pp_count = 400

a = 4
pp_count = 600

a = 5
pp_count = 700
```

We will be running the following code :

```
sc = SparkContext(master='local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.parquet("data.parquet")
print("data columns : {} ".format(df.columns))

sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "table1")
results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) AS pageCount FROM table1 WHERE pp_count>=500").collect()
df.show()
print("initial data count : {}".format(df.count()))
page_count = results[0].pageCount
print("page count : {}".format(page_count))
```

after submitting the application, here is the output :

```
data columns : ['a', 'pp_count']
+---+--------+
|  a|pp_count|
+---+--------+
|  1|     500|
|  2|     750|
|  3|     400|
|  4|     600|
|  5|     700|
+---+--------+

initial data count : 5
page count : 4
```